# Removing tensors for optimising a for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop, pytorch, tensor

I am working on a large code that I'm trying to optimise.
The part of code you see below is a for loop that returns encodings in a tensor. How do I output these numbers in a regular list instead, without going to tensors?

```
def _make_batches(self, lines):
        tokens = [self._tokenize(line) for line in lines]
        lengths = np.array([t.numel() for t in tokens])
        indices = np.argsort(-lengths, kind=self.sort_kind)  # pylint: disable=invalid-unary-operand-type

        def batch(tokens, lengths, indices):
            toks = tokens[0].new_full((len(tokens), tokens[0].shape[0]),
                                      self.pad_index)
            for i in range(len(tokens)):
                toks[i, -tokens[i].shape[0]:] = tokens[i]
            return Batch(srcs=None,
                         tokens=toks,
                         lengths=torch.LongTensor(lengths)), indices

        batch_tokens, batch_lengths, batch_indices = [], [], []
        ntokens = nsentences = 0
        for i in indices:
            if nsentences > 0 and ((self.max_tokens is not None
                                    and ntokens + lengths[i] > self.max_tokens)
                                   or (self.max_sentences is not None
                                       and nsentences == self.max_sentences)):
                yield batch(batch_tokens, batch_lengths, batch_indices)
                ntokens = nsentences = 0
                batch_tokens, batch_lengths, batch_indices = [], [], []
            batch_tokens.append(tokens[i])
            batch_lengths.append(lengths[i])
            batch_indices.append(i)
            ntokens += tokens[i].shape[0]
            nsentences += 1
        if nsentences > 0:
            yield batch(batch_tokens, batch_lengths, batch_indices)
```

This is how I call this function:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = SentenceEncoder("data/model.pt")
    input = [args.string_enc]
    make_batches = s._make_batches
    print([batch[1] for batch, indexes in make_batches(input)])
```

The output is:

```
[tensor([[29733, 20720,     2]])]
```

The desired output is:

```
[29733, 20720,     2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```
a=[torch.tensor([[29733, 20720,     2]])]
b=a[0].squeeze(0).tolist()
print(b)
```

Comment: Thanks! No, I meant avoiding putting the numbers into tensors in the first place as it's computationally expensive as we have a lot of data for this loop.